# CDATA showing up in my HTML page. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gulp, cdata

I have an HTML page but when I load it on my phone there is a long text that begins with something like "CDATA". 
I didn't add anything like that to my page. I minified and concatenated my JavaScript with Gulp into one file. I have the velocity.js and jQuery libraries loaded.
When I reload the page a couple of times the long text is suddenly gone.
How can I get rid of this issue?
I have coded everything on my own and didn't use any libraries expect the ones mentioned above.

I would be really grateful for help! Thanks!

Comment: If you view page source for the page you'll see that the `CDATA` section is appearing in a `<script>` block after `</head>` but before `<body>`.  Try moving the `</head>` tag after the script ends.

Comment: Every script is in the <head> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is the page speed script, inside that script i can see these lines:

```
<script pagespeed_no_defer="">//<![CDATA[
(function(){var g=this,h=function(b,d){var a=b.split("."),c=g;a[0]in c||!c.execScript||c.execScript("var "+a[0]);for(var e;a.length&&(e=a.shift());)a.length||void 0===d?c[e]?c=c[e]:c=c[e]={}:c[e]=d};var l=function(b){var d=b.length;if(0<d){for(var a=Array(d),c=0;c<d;c++)a[c]=b[c];return a}return[]};var m=function(b){var d=window;if(d.addEventListener)d.addEventListener("load",b,!1);else if(d.attachEvent)d.attachEvent("onload",b);else{var a=d.onload;d.onload=function(){b.call(this);a&&a.call(this)}}};var n,p=function(b,d,a,c,e){this.f=b;this.h=d;this.i=a;this.c=e;this.e={height:window.innerHeight||document.documentElement.clientHeight||document.body.clientHeight,width:window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth||document.body.clientWidth};this.g=c;this.b={};this.a=[];this.d={}},q=function(b,d){var a,c,e=d.getAttribute("pagespeed_url_hash");if(a=e&&!(e in b.d))if(0>=d.offsetWidth&&0>=d.offsetHeight)a=!1;else{c=d.getBoundingClientRect();var f=document.body;a=c.top+("pageYOffset"in window?window.pageYOffset:(document.documentElement||f.parentNode||f).scrollTop);c=c.left+("pageXOffset"in window?window.pageXOffset:(document.documentElement||f.parentNode||f).scrollLeft);f=a.toString()+","+c;b.b.hasOwnProperty(f)?a=!1:(b.b[f]=!0,a=a<=b.e.height&&c<=b.e.width)}a&&(b.a.push(e),b.d[e]=!0)};p.prototype.checkImageForCriticality=function(b){b.getBoundingClientRect&&q(this,b)};h("pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality",function(b){n.checkImageForCriticality(b)});h("pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkCriticalImages",function(){r(n)});var r=function(b){b.b={};for(var d=["IMG","INPUT"],a=[],c=0;c<d.length;++c)a=a.concat(l(document.getElementsByTagName(d[c])));if(0!=a.length&&a[0].getBoundingClientRect){for(c=0;d=a[c];++c)q(b,d);a="oh="+b.i;b.c&&(a+="&n="+b.c);if(d=0!=b.a.length)for(a+="&ci="+encodeURIComponent(b.a[0]),c=1;c<b.a.length;++c){var e=","+encodeURIComponent(b.a[c]);131072>=a.length+e.length&&(a+=e)}b.g&&(e="&rd="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(s())),131072>=a.length+e.length&&(a+=e),d=!0);t=a;if(d){c=b.f;b=b.h;var f;if(window.XMLHttpRequest)f=new XMLHttpRequest;else if(window.ActiveXObject)try{f=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")}catch(k){try{f=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(u){}}f&&(f.open("POST",c+(-1==c.indexOf("?")?"?":"&")+"url="+encodeURIComponent(b)),f.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),f.send(a))}}},s=function(){var b={},d=document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");if(0==d.length)return{};var a=d[0];if(!("naturalWidth"in a&&"naturalHeight"in a))return{};for(var c=0;a=d[c];++c){var e=a.getAttribute("pagespeed_url_hash");e&&(!(e in b)&&0<a.width&&0<a.height&&0<a.naturalWidth&&0<a.naturalHeight||e in b&&a.width>=b[e].k&&a.height>=b[e].j)&&(b[e]={rw:a.width,rh:a.height,ow:a.naturalWidth,oh:a.naturalHeight})}return b},t="";h("pagespeed.CriticalImages.getBeaconData",function(){return t});h("pagespeed.CriticalImages.Run",function(b,d,a,c,e,f){var k=new p(b,d,a,e,f);n=k;c&&m(function(){window.setTimeout(function(){r(k)},0)})});})();pagespeed.CriticalImages.Run('/mod_pagespeed_beacon','http://beta.tim-specht.com/sites/Praxis3/','l-uclZP3o3',true,false,'vYDWyUL8cpc');
//]]></script>
```

try removing these lines

Comment: They are not there in my HTML file in my editor. I don't know where they come from.

Comment: I'm not an expert of page speed but I've taken them from your site. maybe you have a nginx or apache pagespeed plugin that add those lines

Comment: So I have to look at the settings of my web server, right?

Comment: That would explain why I only see this on mobile... On my PC I always view the webpage from my local web server.

Comment: that and I also try with these files:<script src="dist/js/libs.min.js.pagespeed.jm.ML5Dv_HjWQ.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="dist/js/scripts.min.js.pagespeed.ce.G9yB05AF13.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will look trough the settings and will do serval test with local server against my web host and when I will find nothing I will try to contact the support of my web server. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I have found an option for page speed optimisation. I turned it off and will have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in a wordpress site in AWS instance with bitnami in my mobile version of the page. The issue here is that bitnami loads pagespeed by default. I solve this connecting via ssh to my server in aws and found this file using "cd .." (you can edit this file via SSH or via FTP). This is the SSH way:

Connect via ssh to your server.

Look for the "httpd.conf" file in:

```
/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

use the "nano" command to open the file.

```
nano /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Then press "ctrl + w" and look for this 2 lines:

```
Include conf/pagespeed.conf
Include conf/pagespeed_libraries.conf
```

use "#" in both lines to comment and save the file:

```
#Include conf/pagespeed.conf
#Include conf/pagespeed_libraries.conf
```

Then restart apache with the command line:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

or use your own restart command line and that's it

Problem solved.

Hope this can help you guys.